# Why FilledCurve and BezierCurve or BSplineCurve do not fit

Tags: graphics, splines

I want to draw the outline of a circle (it's actually the glyph `period` from Cascadia Code font):

```
points = {
  {{600.,-20.},{518.,-20.},{452.,46.},{452.,128.}},
  {{452.,128.},{452.,210.},{518.,276.},{600.,276.}},
  {{600.,276.},{682.,276.},{748.,210.},{748.,128.}},
  {{748.,128.},{748.,46.},{682.,-20.},{600.,-20.}}
};
Graphics /@ {
  {
    PointSize[0.02], Point @ Flatten[points, 1],
    BezierCurve /@ points,
    Opacity[0.2, Blue], FilledCurve[BezierCurve /@ points]
  },
  {
    PointSize[0.02], Point @ Flatten[points, 1],
    BSplineCurve /@ points,
    Opacity[0.2, Red], FilledCurve[BSplineCurve /@ points]
  }
} // GraphicsRow
```

[image]

- Black "circle": drawn by `BezierCurve` or `BSplineCurve`
- Blue region: `FilledCurve @ BezierCurve`
- Red region: `FilledCurve @ BSplineCurve`

Why the curve and the filled region do no fit whether I use `BezierCurve` or `BSplineCurve`?

Comment: The `BezierCurve` corners make sense because it's actually a collection of splines glued together in a C0 continuous way.  `BSplineCurve` looks smoother because they're joined in a C2 continuous way. There is unfortunately no way to make an exact circle with these splines - but you can get close - look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734745/how-to-create-circle-with-bézier-curves

Comment: @flinty I know that the circle can't be represented exactly by Bezier curves. But my question is that why the **filled** region and the enclosed curve do not fit?

Comment: Did you read the docs for `FilledCurve[]`? Try omitting the first point of the second, third, and fourth set of control points before feeding to `FilledCurve[]`: `Graphics[{PointSize[0.02], Point @ Flatten[points, 1], BezierCurve /@ points, Opacity[0.2, Blue], FilledCurve[BezierCurve /@ Join[{First[points]}, Drop[points, 1, 1]]]}]`

Comment: @J.M. Oh really thank you for your comment! It works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Filling in an answer from [@J.M.'s comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/223059/why-filledcurve-and-beziercurve-or-bsplinecurve-do-not-fit#comment567972_223059):

> Did you read the docs for `FilledCurve[]`? Try omitting the first point of the second, third, and fourth set of control points before feeding to `FilledCurve[]`: `Graphics[{PointSize[0.02], Point @ Flatten[points, 1], BezierCurve /@ points, Opacity[0.2, Blue], FilledCurve[BezierCurve /@ Join[{First[points]}, Drop[points, 1, 1]]]}]` –
> J. M. can't deal with it♦ Jun 1, 2020 at 15:07

```
points = {{{600., -20.}, {518., -20.}, {452., 46.}, {452., 128.}},
   {{452., 128.}, {452., 210.}, {518., 276.}, {600., 276.}},
   {{600., 276.}, {682., 276.}, {748., 210.}, {748., 128.}},
   {{748., 128.}, {748., 46.}, {682., -20.}, {600., -20.}}};
Graphics[{PointSize[0.02], Point@Flatten[points, 1], 
  BezierCurve /@ points, Opacity[0.2, Blue], 
  FilledCurve[
   BezierCurve /@ Join[{First[points]}, Drop[points, 1, 1]]]}]
```

[image]